# Looking for datasheet for SHARP LS030Y3DX01 Display

Tags: lcd, datasheet

I am looking for the datasheet for the LS030Y3DX01  LCD display from Sharp.

The display is a 3 inches with the resolution 480x800 pixels.

The only thing I have found is on this web site that requires a paid subscription:

http://www.panelook.com/LS030Y3DX01_SHARP_3.0_LCM_overview_14230.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is a bit of a "non answer" as well but may be useful for others with the same problem in the future. I contacted the LCD divisions in the USA, Singapore and Australia using a company name / e-mail (albeit a small unknown one) and out of the two that responded both wanted information on the project and the likely sales projections.

When I mentioned it was a low-volume application so I'd be purchasing through a reseller things "went quiet" and I didn't get a further response. I can only assume the datasheet either requires an NDA or more likely because they publish other LCD datasheets it's a retired product so they had no incentive to provide it. It's also possible it was never distributed electronically.

I noticed the site you found gives credit for uploading datasheets, so possibly someone with a paper version (or in violation of an NDA) scanned and uploaded it assuming the site is legitimate. One site I found that has a decent list of somewhat similar LCD panels is the following, perhaps you'll find something similar enough that it'll be useful:

http://www.sharp.net.au/articles/components/microelectronics/datasheet-archive/25-to-121-panels/

Update: I was cleaning up my e-mails and had received a response from Earth LCD who I'd found at the time were selling the device, it had an unusual subject and came from an unfamiliar name so I'd disregarded it at the time. The spec number is shown as LCY-1209303D and even though the model number LS030Y3DX01 appears in the document that seems to yield better search results, for example I found:

http://www.encore-electronic.com/media/LS030Y3DX01.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I am having the same problem, I used to work for very large companies and never had problem getting datasheet for any components, but no a days that I am freelance, it is really hard to get access to those "high end" devices such as LCDs and SoCs.

Answer (score 1):

here is [official sharp LCD's](http://www.sharpsma.com/sharpledlcd)

if you can't find it on the site ,you may want to contact sharp electronics [support centre.](http://www.sharpsma.com/support). Send them email  with request.....

if it's not custom made for some other company that should reply.

and i think this question is off topic.

Comment: Thanks, I know the site and tried, but they are not sharing that info with individuals!

Comment: Did you send them email ?

Comment: I sent one to the local office, but no respond from them yet. The ones in the US do not cover France.

Comment: it should not matter just request datasheet from them. tell them that you are interesting in using it with you product.